# Serving a project in Ember using `ember s` triggers file changed

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application, ember-cli

So, I am serving an Ember using `ember s` command. Even though I do not make any changes to the code I keep seeing the entry `file changed <fileName>` in the server startup log, this makes the server start process really slow. I am using Windows 11, however this happened in windows 10 also, ember-cli version `3.8.3`.

There is an issue raised in github with no solution - https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/9055. This is the only mention of this issue I could find.

Hope someone has a solution to this.

Comment: does the behavior still occur if you have watchman installed?

Comment: From what I can understand from this document, https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/, watchman is not required for windows OS.

Comment: hm, do you experience this behavior on a brand new / empty app?

Answer (score 0):

Reason is, windows triggering change event based on last accessed time change for some time. So we need to filter out those change event.

You need to add one if condition in the below files,
node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js
processChange method,

```
//Allow only recently modified files, Since Windows receiving change event here when there is change in accessTime.
if(new Date()-stat.mtime<60000 || new Date()-stat.ctime<60000) {
  this.emitEvent(CHANGE_EVENT, relativePath, stat);
}else {
  console.log('Change event came, but not emitted: file',file);
}
```

I modified in my fork for the reference.
[Link for reference](https://github.com/kumkanillam/sane/blob/33f4c37db8cdc2d4bdb282cc09455d09d56c071d/src/node_watcher.js#L308)